# javascript - Get height of image from url on Chrome

Tags: javascript

I am working with height of image in javascript,

my code:

```
<script>
    var  linkBg = 'http://imageshack.us/a/img24/5489/2013042200001.jpg';
    var bgimg = new Image();
        bgimg.src = linkBg;
        var bgHeight = bgimg.height;
        alert(bgHeight);
</script>
```

my problem is: when I run this script on Firefox, it return the height of images, but on Chrome it return 0.

How can I fix this problem using only javascript without Jquery, thanks for any help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wait until image is fully loaded , like this:

```
var imgHeight , imgWidth;
bgimg.onload = function() {
   imgHeight = bgimg.naturalHeight;
   imgWidth = bgimg.naturalWidth;    
}
```

Comment: @johnITBonuc, you'll notice that if you execute your code line by line through Chrome's console (Ctrl+Shift+J), it works, since the browser is given time to load the image.